# Text Analysis using R

Tags: r

I have some e-mail subject lines with their respective read rates as well as spam rates. Is it possible to use text mining in R to analyse the subject lines and the words/ pahses that contribute to the read/spam rates? Please advise..

```
E-mail subjects          Spam % Read %
Hottest Hues for Spring!    3.00%   12.00%
New Styles Just for You     0.00%   17.00%
We've Got the Perfect Fit!  0.00%   19.00%
Save on Dresses and More!   5.00%   20.00%
More Online Deals Inside    2.04%   13.19%
```

Comment: Yes it is possible to do this in R. The success of such and analysis strongly depends on the model which you are using, therefore I think it is more a theoretical question than a programming question. I would recommend to ask the community at Cross Validated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tm package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html. Also, a good place to start is the task views on CRAN. In this case take a look at the Natural Language Processing task view http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for matt_k's answer. basically the standard way to go: CRAN task views if you're exploring the field. So this is rather an addition to his links.

Plus, you might want to look at [Mark van der Loo's page here](http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2013/08/09/approximate-string-matching-in-r/) who works in the field and provides some examples on approximate string matching. He's the author of the [stringdist](http://www.markvanderloo.eu/yaRb/2013/02/26/the-stringdist-package/) package.

Answer (score 1):

It's surely possible, like

```
df <- read.table(sep=";", header=T, quote="", text="
subject;spam;read
Hottest Hues for Spring!;3.00;12.00
New Styles Just for You;0.00;17.00
We've Got the Perfect Fit!;0.00;19.00
Save on Dresses and More!;5.00;20.00
More Online Deals Inside;2.04;13.19")
library(tm)
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$subject))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control=list(weighting=weightBin))
tmat_ <- as.matrix(dtm)
fit.spam <- lm(df$spam ~ tmat_)
summary(fit.spam)
```

But it will take much effort and know-how to get meaningful results and interpret them.

**Update:**

If the model fits the data, it will tell you which words yield higher read rates. Just as an artificial example:

```
set.seed(1)
weights <- c("hot"=2, "dresses"=5, "pants"=-3, "only"=1) 
ic <- 6L
idx <- replicate(n=10, sample(1:length(weights), size=sample(1:length(weights), size=1)))
df <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(idx, function(x) {
  cbind(paste(names(weights)[x], collapse=" "), sum(weights[x])+ic)
})))
names(df) <- c("subject", "read")
df$read <- as.numeric(as.character(df$read))
df
#                   subject read
# 1            dresses only   12
# 2  hot pants dresses only   11
# 3          hot only pants    6
# 4       dresses pants hot   10
# 5      only dresses pants    9
# 6  hot dresses only pants   11
# 7             hot dresses   13
# 8  dresses only pants hot   11
# 9                    only    7
# 10       only hot dresses   14
library(tm)
corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(df$subject))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp, control=list(weighting= weightTf))
tmat_ <- as.matrix(dtm)
fit.read <- lm(df$read ~ tmat_)
summary(fit.read)
#                  Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
#   (Intercept)   6.000e+00  4.802e-16  1.249e+16   <2e-16 ***
#   tmat_dresses  5.000e+00  3.199e-16  1.563e+16   <2e-16 ***
#   tmat_hot      2.000e+00  3.116e-16  6.418e+15   <2e-16 ***
#   tmat_only     1.000e+00  3.409e-16  2.934e+15   <2e-16 ***
#   tmat_pants   -3.000e+00  2.762e-16 -1.086e+16   <2e-16 ***
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 3.862e-16 on 5 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:      1 
# F-statistic: 9.455e+31 on 4 and 5 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks for providing me a start to this. I read that you are involved in email marketing. This question revolves around email marketing data. Could you suggest what other factors except for the raw data as well as R functions' knowledge would be required to help interpret the results.

Comment: Depends and may even begin with extracting email data itself, as R has no imaplib like python. You may need to program functions on your own, adapt existing ones, choose the right ones to get a good model that fits the data well. Browse through this http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html, browse through that http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SocialSciences.html, ...

Comment: PS: Have a look at RapidMiner, which has graphical user interface and powerful text mining & modeling features as well.

Comment: the code above did not give any significant result maybe because the dataset was very small. Is it possible to import an excel file into R that has many more such subject lines? Also, I just wasnted to know if the above code is taking into account the read rate and spam rates. I am sorry, my questions may sound silly and that's because I am new to R, let alone figuring out text mining in it. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @user3151086 Your question does not sound silly. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for the codes. I think the next apt step for me is to do some homework myself and go through the articles in details and get my data to make more sense with ofcourse the help of your codes. Is it okay if I seek your help again in a few days if I get stuck please.